# PyroCMS 2.0 - Enabling a module makes all images disappear

Tags: image, module, pyrocms

When I enable my custom module, all the images (within  tags) disappear. It happens only on some of my custom built modules.

I had similar problem (not sure if exactly the same) before with a module that was pretty small and straightforward. Eventually I started changing encoding of every file in that module from ANSI to UTF-8 in notepad++ while refreshing the page. At some point images started showing up.

This module now has 400 files in it and I don't want to change every single one of them to perhaps finally see images.

Paths are correct.

Did anyone run into similar problem?

PyroCMS version is 2.0 RC and it is multi-site version.

Comment: 2.0.0 RC? We're on 2.1.5 or 2.2.0-beta1. Why not use one of those?

Comment: It runs 15 websites now, need some spare time to fix possible problems during update.

Comment: Even upgrading to 2.0.0 would be better than running 2.0.0 RC1. That's pretty dangerous to do dude.

Comment: Tell me about it:)I work for a dude that bought it and runs it on his server.He already hired 3 developers throughout a year or two, who tinkered with core module files and even codeigniter libraries to satisfy requirements of some of these websites. Now it's a pandora's box, whatever you do, the outcome is hardly predictable and after e.g. writing my own module I get e-mail a day later that some other website is broken..., so now I need to fix 2 websites and from 20 hours predicted I've spent around 160 hours, mostly fixing broken things. IMO he needs to leave it as it is and install new one.

Comment: You can install a new PyroCMS Professional 2.2 install and move the sites over one by one just by copying the `sitefoo_` prefixed files and copying the "core_sites" entry. Seriously, it sounds like your code is an insane mess (not your fault of course) so trying to support it is not going to work. Plus it's old, so sod that. Sorry bro.

Comment: I appreciate your compassion:) What you say is exactly what is intended to happen. Thanks for your reassurance and valuable opinion. Have an awesome day.